# AndroidでpopBackStackした時のライフサイクル

Tags: android, android-fragments

AndroidのFragmentをaddToBackStackしたあとで、popBackStackと呼ぶとリプレースを取り消しできますが、popBackStack後のリプレースされたフラグメント、つまりリプレース前に表示されていたフラグメントのライフサイクルはどの状態になるのでしょうか。

今作成しているアプリでpopBackStackを呼び出すとリプレースされえたフラグメントが何も表示されずに困っております。

ご教授ねがえますでしょうか。よろしくお願いします。

追記 PagerAdapterをnewしている箇所

```
adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getChildFragmentManager());
mViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(2);
mViewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
mViewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(this);
```

Comment: 想像での質問なのですが、Fragment内にFragment(ViewPager含む)を貼っていて、popBackStack()で戻ってくると中身が空っぽ　みたいな現象でしょうか？

Comment: その通りです。外側のViewPagerは表示されますが内側のFragmentが表示されない状態です。

Comment: PagerAdapterをnewしている部分のコードを貼り付けてください！

Comment: @fkm 質問に追記しました。

Comment: `getChildFragmentManager()`をちゃんと渡しているのでここは問題なさそうですね。もひとつ心当たりのあるところがあるので、手元で試してから回答します

Comment: @fkm なんかすみません。わざわざありがとうございます。